# How to put focus() cursor behind text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with React and need help with useRef hook concrete with focus() javascript function.
Everything work fine but there is small fault. I want after click on edit button focus cursor on textarea. Cursor focus but it is on start of the line. I want blink cursor behind text, so that I can immediately continue writing and editing the text.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEdit) {
      refUpdate.current.focus()
    }
  }, [isEdit])

  

<textarea
        type="text"
        className="update-textarea"
        value={value}
        ref={refUpdate}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
```

After that focus work, but blink at the start of text line. My goal is put cursor behind edited text.
Thanks.

Comment: Use ```setSelectionRange()```, this sets the start and end positions of the current text selection in an input field.